# How can I reference an item within recordholder in Power Apps?

Tags: powerapps

I joined two collections and the result comprises columns type text and 1 column with type recordholder as the image shows. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nin7v.png). If I open this record holder I can see the column that I am interested in that is called Proyecto: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYBzw.png), but I don't know how to access to this particular field. I tried ThisItem.recordHolder, Thisitem.recordHolder.proyecto, Thisitem.recordholder[@proyecto] but none of them work.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using the ungroup() function. I couldn't reference the elements inside Recordholder by using '.' neither '[]'.
Ungroup() is the solution to expand the table and then you can call any element inside using the traditional way.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerApps fields in nested or resulting tables can be referenced like:

```
ThisItem.recordHolder.Value.proyecto
```

or

```
Thisitem.recordHolder.Result.proyecto
```

Comment: I cannot access that way. It is so strange